# getting memory error after running pivot function

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I tried the code below and get a memory error. I needed to expand my dataframe from long to wide with duplicate index numbers.

```
df.pivot(index='id',columns='idx')[['notes','createdAt','createdBy']]
```

Comment: Please provide more information. How big is the dataframe? What exactly is the error?

Comment: @SimonN its 145772 rows × 5 columns

Comment: ...and what is the exact error? Please add the stack trace to your question.